# Why I cannot use Java-Style QMapIterator in QMap.erase()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying this code in Qt 5.12:

```
//Definition of map
QMap<int, ZoneData*>           mapId2Pointer_;

//Some values filled in mapId2Pointer_ here...

        QMapIterator<int, ZoneData*> iteratorId2Pointer(mapId2Pointer_);
        while (iteratorId2Pointer.hasNext())
        {
            iteratorId2Pointer.next();
            if (iteratorId2Pointer.value() == _climbZoneData)
            {
                iteratorId2Pointer = mapId2Pointer_.erase(iteratorId2Pointer); //<- ERROR
            }
        }
```

But, in the last line of code compiler gives this error:

error: no matching function for call to 'QMap::erase(QMapIterator&)'
                     iteratorId2Pointer = mapId2Pointer_.erase(iteratorId2Pointer);

I've seen a lot of examples and googled a lot, with no success. All examples look similar to the above one, every one uses a QMapIterator as parameter in QMap::erase() call. But no conversion from QMapIterator to QMap::iterator seems to be possible in my code.

What can be the reason of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QMapIterator` is a "Java-style iterator" and `QMap::iterator` is a "STL-style iterator". They are not compatible; you need to use one or the other.

You can iterate using a `QMap::iterator` like this:

```cpp
QMap<int, ZoneData*>::iterator i = mapId2Pointer_.begin();
while(i != mapId2Pointer_.end()) {
    if (i.value() == _climbZoneData) {
        i = mapId2Pointer_.erase(i);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Note that if you weren't erasing things in the middle (which invalidates your iterator, requiring you to set it to the return value from `erase`), you could use a for loop instead.

Comment: Oh my. You're completely right. I assumed the Java's iterator was interchangeable with STL's one. I didn't notice that subtle difference. That's why I ended looking for some (non-existing) typecasting between them.

Simple, clear and concise. Thanks!!